# How to ignore devServer settings in vue.config.js when building for staging environment?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I'm building an app with Vue. I needed `https` working on my local environment for dev and testing purposes. I successfully created the necessary certificates [following this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec). To get the dev server to use them I copied the `server.key` and `server.crt` files into the root of my project and left the `rootCA.pem` file in `~/.ssh`. I added an entry in `/etc/hosts` to alias localhost for my domain like:

```
127.0.0.1 example.test
```

I then edited `vue.config.js` in the root of my project to look like:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'example.test',
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.HOME + '/.ssh/rootCA.pem')
    }
  }
}
```

This works **great** locally. My problem is on my staging server.

My staging server is running ubuntu (16.04) and has an actual SSL cert (i.e. not self-signed) installed using `certbot` (LetsEncrypt). My project is a static frontend so I am serving it with `nginx` configured to point to the `/dist` directory and make the project available at `staging.example.com`. This was all working fine before I added the `devServer` config in `vue.config.js` above.

#### What I *expect* to happen:

When I build the project for staging, i.e.

```
npm run build -- --mode staging
```

I expected it to ignore the `devServer` config section since `NODE_ENV === 'production'` (set in my `.env.staging` file).

#### What *actually* happens:

The build process fails, complaining that:

```
Error loading vue.config.js:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './server.key'
```

#### Question: How do I get the build process to ignore the `devServer` section of `vue.config.js` when building for "staging" or "production?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vue.config.js` doesn't automatically detect the environment. As [it says in the Vue CLI configuration docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration):

> If you need conditional behavior based on the environment, or want to directly mutate the config, use a function (which will be lazy evaluated after the env variables are set). The function receives the resolved config as the argument. Inside the function, you can either mutate the config directly, OR return an object which will be merged.

How to actually do this was not immediately clear to me. Here's what ended up working:

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      config.devServer = {
        host: 'qzuku.test',
        // https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec
        https: {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./qzukuDevServer.key'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('./qzukuDevServer.crt'),
          ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.HOME + '/.ssh/rootDevCA.pem')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also possible to use a ternary operator : 

`{
  devServer: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.key')
    }
  } : undefined`

Comment: This was not immediately clear to me either. I even looked through the docs and didn't see the article you linked to! Thank you!